# WP 4.4 admin 500 error after update - wp_register_style - Braxton theme

Tags: wordpress

After the wordpress update to 4.4 i got the blank admin after the process finished. WP_debug true reveals the following error for wp-admin

Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in `/var/www/vhosts/site.net/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php` on line `3787` Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly.

Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in `/var/www/vhosts/site.net/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php` on line `3787 Notice: Undefined index: enableMultiple`in `/var/www/vhosts/site.net/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/menufication111/menufication.php` on line 102 Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in `/var/www/vhosts/site.net/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php` on line 3619 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in `/var/www/vhosts/site.net/httpdocs/wp-includes/meta.php` on line 844

Even with deactivation of all the plugins error is still present. Only wheb I switch the theme it withdraws and wp-admin can be accessed.

Here is my function.php of the theme: 
http://pastebin.com/01XJunTf

Video that explains the problem is to follow. 
https://vid.me/6Utj

Every help is much appreciated.

Best regards, 
Igor

Comment: Error messages point at three different files and include exact numbers of lines that are wrong. Please edit your question to add links to files in question.

Comment: Igor, a quick Google search showed other instances of folks having the same issue with the same theme. It seems to be theme related rather than WP core related.Have you contacted the theme developer?

Answer (score 0):

It was memory limit problem if anyone encounters the same issue.

Thanks for help. 
Igor